# How can I Deserialize nested json with DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, json, datacontractjsonserializer

I'm trying to deserialize json like this:

```
{
    "version": 3070,
    "settings": [
        [
            "settingInteger",
            0,
            "1513486800",
            {
                "param": "A"
            }
        ],
        [
            "settingBool",
            1,
            "false",
            {
                "param": "B"
            }
        ],
        [
            "settingString",
            2,
            "somedata",
            {
                "param" : "C"
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

So I've tried to Deserialize into this class with `DataContraceJsonSerializer`:

```
 [DataContract]
 public class SettingSet
 {
     [DataMember(Name = "version")]
     public int Version { get; set; }
     [DataMember(Name = "settings)]
     public Setting[] Settings { get; set; }
 }
 [DataContract]
 public class Setting
 {
     [DataMember(Order = 0)]
     public string OptionName { get; set; }
     [DataMember(Order = 1)]
     public SettingType Type { get; set; }
     [DataMember(Order = 2)]
     public string Value { get; set; }
     [DataMember(Order = 3)]
     public Dictionary<string, string> Parameters { get; set; }
 }
```

But I could only get `Version` and Array of empty `Settings`.
If I use `object[][]` instead of `Setting[]`, I can get some data, but `param` is still inaccessible.
Is there any ways to solve this or should I use other JSON libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

SettingSet settingSet = serializer.Deserialize<SettingSet>(jSon);
```

Comment: This throws `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Type 'Setting' is not supported for deserialization of an array.'`

Comment: try to use  Settings as Collection or list

Comment: in both System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<Setting> and List<Setting>, it happens

Comment: your settings is looking like this:                                                                  
  public List<List<object>> settings { get; set; }

Comment: Thanks, List<List<object>> and object[][] both worked.

Comment: but, you mean, there is no way to directly serialize into Setting[] and I have to cast into it?

Comment: try to write it like this { 
  "Version": 0,
  "Settings": [{ 
  "OptionName": "asd",
  "Value": "asd",
  "Parameters": "asd"
}]
}